# Как заменить определенный участок текста в файле WORD с помощью питона

Tags: python, ms-word, replace

Все как и в заголовке - нужно взять документ формата .docx и поменять в нем определенные слова на введенные ранее пользователем.

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document('F://PythonProjects//Trash//example.docx')
paras = doc.paragraphs

name = input()

for para in paras:
    para = para.text.split(' ')
    for word in para:
        //'NAME,' - строка в исходном файле
        if word == 'NAME,':
            word = name + ','
    para = ' '.join(para)
```

Ошибки не возникает, но и ничего не работает, точнее работает все кроме замены слова на другое.

Кто то может подсказать что я сделал не так?

Comment: может, попробуете вместо `para.text.split(' ')` написать `para.text.split('')`?

Comment: Тогда, вместо списка из слов, у меня будет список из символов.

Comment: Беда в том, что все так то работает, просто в изначальном  файле ничего не меняется.

Comment: нет, у вас как раз будет список слов.

Comment: То есть вы хотите сказать, что если разделитем вместо пробела будет ничего - у меня каким то чудом появится список из слов?

Comment: Как и ожидалось - возникает ошибка -
 ValueError: empty separator. 
А теперь я бы хотел узнать ответ на свой вопрос, а не спорить насчет вещей, которые я уже по 20 раз проверил

Comment: Да, мой косяк. надо так: `para.text.split()`

Comment: По сути произошло абсолютно то же самое

Comment: а как вы сохраняете измененные данные в текст обратно?

Comment: Вот здесь вся проблема. Сначала я делаю из строки список слов, ищу нужное, меняю его в списке на ввод пользователя и собираю список обратно в целую строку. Но в самом файле ничего не меняется

Comment: А как "оно поменяется", если вы не сохраняете изменения?

Comment: Вот для того чтобы это узнать я и опубликовал данный вопрос

Comment: А тут нет проблем с путем 'F://PythonProjects//Trash//example.docx'? Двойные слеши ставят для экранирования, причем это только для \ работает, для `/` так не делают. Поэтому или `'F:/PythonProjects/Trash/example.docx'`, или `'F:\\PythonProjects\\Trash\\example.docx'`, или `r'F:\PythonProjects\Trash\example.docx'` (тут raw-строка). Еще у вас нет сохранения через метод `save`

Comment: Если вам нужно заполнить шаблон файла какими-то данными, то можно использовать библиотеку [python-docx-template](https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, код можно сократить и не забыть записать внесенные изменения:

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document(docx = 'test.docx')

paras = doc.paragraphs

name = "Вася"

for para in paras:
    para.text = para.text.replace('NAME', name)

doc.save('test1.docx')
```